# How to Separate two Separate sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $A,B$ be two subsets of the given metric space $(X,d)$ such that
>   $\overline{A}\cap B=\overline{B}\cap A=\emptyset$. Prove that there
>   exist open sets $U\supseteq A$ and $V\supseteq B$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

It's obvious that for each $a\in A$, we have $r_a:=d(a,B)>0$. Similarly for each $b\in B$, $r_b:=d(b,A)>0$.

Now want to construct a cover for $A$ and $B$ with somethings ***just similar to*** $\{B_{\frac{r_a}2}(a)\}_{a\in A}$ and $\{B_{\frac{r_b}{2}}(b)\}_{b\in B}$. But I can't find neither a *uniform* radius, nor a way to make the covers separate.

I don't think $d(A,B)$ is necessarily *zero*. If it were $0$, we had such a uniform radius $\frac {d(A,B)}3$ !

Answer (score 1):

The sets $U=\bigcup_{a\in A}B(a,\frac13r_a)$ and $V=\bigcup_{b\in B}B(b,\frac13r_b)$ are evidently open with $A\subseteq U$, $B\subseteq V$.

Also $U\cap V=\varnothing$.

This statement is proved below.

---

If $x\in U\cap V$ then $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ must exist with:

$$x\in B\left(a,\frac{1}{3}r_{a}\right)\cap B\left(b,\frac{1}{3}r_{b}\right)$$

Then:

$r_{a}\leq d\left(a,b\right)\leq d\left(a,x\right)+d\left(x,b\right)<\frac{1}{3}r_{a}+\frac{1}{3}r_{b}$

and also

$r_{b}\leq d\left(a,b\right)\leq d\left(a,x\right)+d\left(x,b\right)<\frac{1}{3}r_{a}+\frac{1}{3}r_{b}$

Summation gives:

$r_{a}+r_{b}<\frac{2}{3}r_{a}+\frac{2}{3}r_{b}$ wich is not true.

A contradiction has been found.

---

**edit**:

My choice for $\frac13r_a$ was somehow for safety. I see now that $\frac12r_a$ would have worked too.